# Track Slideshow With jQuery DIVs

Tags: jquery, css

Is there a clear way in Javascript to change a series of DIVs in order to track where in a series a slideshow is currently at?

There are four frames (#a1-#a4) that move based clicks on a DIV called "content". Here's the code for the element I'm trying to add to track where the user is at.

HTML

```
<div id="content">
<div id="indicator">
<div id="dot" class="selected" onClick="location.href='#a1'"></div>
<div id="dot" class="unselected" onClick="location.href='#a2'"></div>
<div id="dot" class="unselected" onClick="location.href='#a3'"></div>
<div id="dot" class="unselected" onClick="location.href='#a4'"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#content {
width:100%;
height:32px;
background-color:red;
}
#indicator {
float:left;
position:absolute;
display:table;
left:5.5%;
top:74%;
margin:0;
text-align: center;
-moz-user-select:none;
-webkit-user-select:none;
z-index:10;
}
#dot {
float:left;
width:16px;
height:16px;
margin-left:8px;
background-color:#D7D7D7;
}
#dot:hover {
background-color:#FFF;
cursor:pointer;
}
#dot.selected {
background-color:#787878;
}
#dot.unselected {
background-color:#D7D7D7;
}
```

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#content").click(function () {
$("#dot").toggleClass("selected unselected");
$("#dot").siblings().toggleClass("selected unselected");
});
});
```

There is also an example up at [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GargantuanMedia/hL3pfy09/3/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally speaking, an ***id*** should be used for ***unique*** elements, that is to say you shouldn't have multiple ids on a page. If you are going to target multiple elements, use ***class***.

Since you want to target the indicator dots after a click on the #content div has been made, @Nelu answer won't work. Instead you could do this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#content").click(function () {
        slideTrackIndicator();
    });
    function slideTrackIndicator(){
        var numDots = $(".dot").length,
            $currentDot = $('.selected'),
            currentDotNumber = $currentDot.index();
        if (currentDotNumber < numDots - 1) {
            $currentDot.toggleClass("selected unselected").next().toggleClass("selected unselected");
        } else {
            $currentDot.toggleClass("selected unselected").siblings().eq(0).toggleClass("selected unselected");
        }
    }
});
```

see the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zryyxcag/)

Comment: This is excellent, Gabereal. However, the user can also go backwards. Is there a way to write a .previous toggleClass to handle this kind of backwards movement?

Comment: if they can also go backwards, then there must be a target element somewhere you can put a class or id on to listen to in your click handler. most implementations have a ```<sometag id="previous"></sometag>``` and ```<sometag id="next"></sometag>``` element you can bind your click function to, where sometag is a div, span, anchor etc. in which case you would change the ***if*** and ***else*** statements in ```slideTrackIndicator()``` function accordingly. and yes, there is a prev method in jquery http://api.jquery.com/prev/

Comment: I've added a "backbutton" and a "nextbutton" for each step backwards or forward. However, if a user goes back from the initial start - all dots disappear. Is there a method to change this?

Comment: The malfunctioning previous example is at a Fiddle here: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/GargantuanMedia/02pk6wo3/3/)

Comment: Looks like this is turning into a whole different question. You should probably edit your question and i'll have to update my answer...

Comment: Update the original question? That is unnecessary, isn't it? I have taken your advice and constructed a Fiddle around your answer. There is only one bug (disappearing dot on previous) left in this code.

Comment: @MisterMedia the reason i suggested it is that you are straying from the scope of the original question a little bit and its getting to be more of a "how do i build a jquery slider" question. there are a ton of those out there already, many for free. anyway, here's one approach. not the most DRY but it does the job. http://jsfiddle.net/upj6zmxw/

Answer (score 0):

Change `dot` from an **id** to a **class** and try something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".dot").click(function () {
        $(this).addClass("selected").removeClass("unselected");
        $(this).siblings().addClass("unselected").removeClass("selected");                
    });
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nmalancea/Lwqn61dL/)

`id` should be **unique** in an HTML document.
`class` should be used for **reused** selectors.

---

**Update:**
@gabereal is right. I misunderstood the question.
It will be useful however to have the functionality on `$(".dot").click` as well.